# Update table view when present popOver

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, tableview, popover

I have a custom table view cell with `UITextField` and `UIButton` and when trigger button show popOver, I want to when selected cell in popOver view table view textField fill with text, but not working my code.

**my code:**

In popOver controller :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! chooseReciverTableCell
    valueToPass = cell.nameLabel.text

    print(valueToPass)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification", object: nil)

}
```

in tableViewController:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        self.bCell = UINib(nibName: "buttonCell", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! buttonCell
 textField.text = self.reciver.valueToPass
        self.chooseTableView.reloadData()

  }
```